# Is there any way to implement direction using google-maps plugin of 'Ionic Native'

Tags: android, angular, google-maps-api-3, ionic-native

I usually implements google maps by calling google-maps api. Recently I decided to use google-maps plugin of 'Ionic Native' to make thing smoother. I have successfully implemented markers in maps and everything was working fine. But when I decided to implement routes between two points, I found that ionic native didn't have a function to implement this direction service.

So my question is

1. Is there any method to implement direction using google-maps plugin?
2. If there is no such method, Is it possible to implement this two kind of maps in one application and show direction in one map and other services in another map? Is that really a good practise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Maps JavaScript API v3 for direction, then parse the result, and draw it using polyline and marker.
Some people use the Google Directions API.

Or just launch the Google Maps application using 
https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator

Comment: This method really worked. What I done is I used google maps javascript API v3 and fetched response for route, this response contains overview_polyline which has all the LatLng of that route as encoded, I just decoded this overview_polyline using google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath() and created an array of LatLng, then I draw a polyline using this array. This is the method I used, if there is any better way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Will it make the application slow? Do you have an working example? Can you please share it with us?